# Troubles when debugging azure service cloud with certain VM sizes

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-cloud-services

for costs puropoes in our cloud serviced we had to change VM sizes (from Standard v2 to v3) and the deployment to azure works like a charm. But when i try to debug application, we have encountered this error:

Microsoft Azure Tools: Error: Element 'vmsize' is not a valid role size 'Standard_D2_v3'.
Microsoft Azure Tools: Error reading service definition file: C:\azure\ServiceDefinition.csdef

We use VS 2017.